# Hi, My submenu doesn't show on hover on desktop. Visible only on mobile device. Any idea why?

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, dropdown, submenu

My submenu disappeared, it doesn't show anymore when I hover over the menu item. I checked the menu section on my WP dashboard and it's there and assigned to show. The submenu still show on mobile device but on full browser the submenu items stopped showing up. Any idea why? Theme is Accumove, address is smartmovelondon.com.

Comment: Sorry, we cannot possibly help without seeing relevant code - any answer at the moment will just be a guess. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - it is not safe for SO to rely on an external link which may either disappear or the code get corrected, thus rendering your question useless for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

I need to see your WordPress dashboard. Without seeing your dashboard, I can't answer your question correctly.

[Contact me](https://www.linkedin.com/in/akash-halder-801604243/) for your solution.

Comment: It seems to me your submenu hover effect set only for mobile. It can be set via javascript or css. Please check your code.